# Prove that $x\left(1+2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, monotone-functions

I am having difficulties proving that

> $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto\begin{cases}x\left(1+2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right),&\text{if }x\neq0\\0,&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$ is differentiable with $f'(0) > 0$.
>
> Also show that $f$ is not strictly monotonically increasing in neighbourhood of point $0$.

So I must show that $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$  has an interval in which $f$ is strictly monotonically decreasing and can use the properties that $\sin'(x) = \cos(x)$, $\cos'(x) = -\sin(x)$ and $\sin(2\pi n) = 0$, $\cos(2 \pi n) = 1$.

I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In the second question starting "Also show" it only says to prove $f$ is not strictly monotone increasing in a neighborhood of $0.$ This is not as strong as your version, that $f$ must be strictly decreasing in some neighborhood of $0.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for every $x\neq0$ $f$ is obviously differentiable since it is product, sum and synthesis of function that are differentiable. We have to give a closer look to $x_0=0$.

By definition, we have:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\left(1+2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\right)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\left[1+2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\right]$$

So, $f'(0)>0$ **if and only if the above limit does exist** and is strictly positive. For the calculation of the above limit, we have:

$$\left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\leq|x|\cdot1\mbox{, since $\sin\phi\leq1$}$$
So, we have:
$$0\leq\lim_{x\to0}\left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\leq\lim_{x\to0}|x|=0\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to0}\left|x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|=0\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$$
So, for our first limit, we have:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[1+2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\right]=1+2\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=1+2\cdot0=1$$

So:
$$f'(0)=1>0$$
which is what has been requested.

**EDIT:**(I did not see the last part of the question)
For every other $x\neq0$, we have:
$$f'(x)=1+2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+x\left(2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{2}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$
or, shorter:
$$f'(x)=1+4x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

So, let $\epsilon>0$ and let $x_k=\frac{1}{k\pi}$. There is, by Archimedes-Eudoxus Principle, a $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$, such that:
$$\frac{1}{k\pi}<\epsilon$$
for every $k\geq k_0$. So, for every $k>k_0$, we have:
$$f'(x_k)=1+\frac{4}{k\pi}\sin(k\pi)-2\cos(k\pi)=1+2\cdot(-1)^{k}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}3&\mbox{if $k$ is even}\\-1&\mbox{if $k$ is odd}\end{array}\right.$$

So, in any open neighbourhood $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ of $0$, $f'$ takes both positive and negative values and, hence, $f$ is not strictly monotonous there.

Comment: Not quite.  You were asked to show that $f$ is NOT monotonically increasing in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Yeah, I "mispressed" the answer button (tab-enter is done mechanically sometimes! :P)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Compute $f'(x)$ for $x \ne 0$.
2. $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=1+2x \sin(1/x) \to 1$ for $x \to 0$.
3. $f'(\frac{1}{n \pi})=(-1)^{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$